# Checking if a float is not a number

Tags: c++

This code is from UE4 and I have some trouble understanding it.

```
static FORCEINLINE bool IsNaN( float A ) 
{
    return ((*(uint32*)&A) & 0x7FFFFFFF) > 0x7F800000;
}
```

(uint32 is just an unsigned int)

The first part is interpreting a float as an uint32, that is the easy part but why bitwise and it with `0x7FFFFFFF`? What are the last 4 bits telling us and why do we compare the result with `0x7F800000`?

Comment: Perhaps by using the *standard* [`isnan`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) function?

Comment: I'm more curious why they even decided to make an own implementation of `isnan`... It should be just as optimized in every decent standard implementation.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN. The IEEE 754 32-bit NaN is `s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx`, where `x > 0`.

Comment: You need to tag UE4 too.

Comment: @Raphael, Perhaps they don't use C++11.

Comment: @chris makes sense... I thought that it was already there before C++11 but apparently not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This definition follows the NaN definition provided in IEEE 754 standard.

> In IEEE 754 standard-conforming floating point storage formats, NaNs are identified by specific, pre-defined bit patterns unique to NaNs.

`0x7FFFFFFF` is the largest value, that can be represented on 31 bits. In this case, it simply ignores the bit sign, because:

> The sign bit does not matter.

`0x7F800000` is the mask for bits of the exponential field.

> For example, a bit-wise IEEE floating-point standard single precision
>   (32-bit) NaN would be: s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx where s
>   is the sign (most often ignored in applications) and x is non-zero
>   (the value zero encodes infinities).

Where `s111 1111 1xxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` with `s = 0` (ignored by anding with `0x7FFFFFFF`) and `x = 0` is equal to `0x7F800000`.

`operator >` is used, because if **any** bit in the significand is set (any `x`), resulting value will be greater than `0x7F800000`.

And why should it be set? Because:

> The state/value of the remaining bits [...] are not defined by the standard except that they must not be all zero.

Source: [NaN on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Answer (score 3):

This is the definition a NaN. You can read this in detail on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).
`0x7FFFFFFF` is used because the sign bit does not matter in the check.
The definition says that for a nan the exponential field is filled with ones and some non-zero number is in the significand.
`0x7F80000` this is the bit mask for the exponential field. So if a bit is set in the significand the the number must be larger than `0x7F800000`

Note that is assumes that a `sizeof(float) == 4`.

Answer (score 0):

### isnan()

You can either use the [isnan](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/isnan) implementation which is environment defined but has historical issues (it was a macro, then became a function under `tr1` and in some implementations is still a macro).

### f != f

Or, in case you cant track it in your standard library, you can rely on the IEEE standard stating that NaN values have the special property of being different from itself: `f != f`.
Check out this [really interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1573715/3374591) from Stephen Canon who was in the **IEEE-754** committee, and explains the rationale behind it.

note that not all compilers will respect this when some optimization flags are turned on (for instance `-ffast-math` on `gcc`).